# How can I tell Chrome which input fields to remember / which will be the login credentials?

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, input

I have a Sign Up form which contains these input fields (in order):

- **e-mail** (autocomplete="email", type="email")
- **(user)name** (type="text")
- **(display)name** (type="text")
- **password** (autocomplete="new-password",type="password")
- **password again** (type="password")

If the user submits this form, Chrome suggests to **save the password** but with the **names** instead of the **e-mail field** (which will be needed to login). How can I tell Google Chrome (and other browsers) which input fields to remember / which will be the login credentials? (in my case: e-mail and password). Is there some kind of HTML5 code for this?

I have tried so far:

- autocomplete="false" , autocomplete="off"  and autocomplete="new-password" on the name fields ( Not working)
- autocomplete="false", autocomplete="off" on the signup form itself (not working)
- give an unrecognizable id and name to the name fields (id="usnm" instead of id="username") (not working)

I need to achieve:

- Tell the browser that DO NOT remember the sign up form input values as credentials OR
- Tell the browser exactly which data values to remember (e-mail + pass)

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Stacy-H  at UX Forums, I could finally solve this mystery. Here is the solution:

In the HTML I've **labeled** the email field as "username". ( I guess lack of the labels caused Chrome's confusion on the subject. )

My form looks something like this now:

```
<!-- Email -->
<label>Username:</label>
<input required  autocomplete="email"  type="email" name="signup_email" id="signup_email" placeholder="E-mail" />   

<!-- Username -->
<input  type="text" placeholder="Username"  id="signup_username"  name="signup_username" />

<!--  Name -->
<input required type="text" autocomplete="name" placeholder="Display Name"  id="signup_name"  name="signup_name" />

<!-- Password -->
<input required pattern=".{8,}" autocomplete="new-password" placeholder="Password" />

<!--  Confirm Password -->
<input  required pattern=".{8,}" autocomplete="new-password" placeholder="Password again"/>
```